# Hazelcast kills client connections after member restart

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using 3.8.1, I have noticed some issues around the reconnection behaviors around clients after when members are bounced. Despite setting the reconnection attempts, the clients often disconnect anyway after logging repeated warnings about unable to get a cluster connection -- this despite there always being at least one surviving member at all times.

So why does the disconnect happen? I believe that if there is a least one member alive, no client should ever be disconnected.
And why does a client repeatedly log and warn after a member has bounced?

The test:
I have 2 members joined.
I have 3 clients that connect to both members via tcp.
Clients are configured to reconnect 1000 times.
Client 1 loops and simply put a random value to the same key.
Clients 2 & 3 are listeners to this map and log the update.

Steps:
Start member 1, member 2.
Start both client 2, 3 (listeners).
Start client 1 (writer).
Everything ok at this point. No warnings in logs.

Bounce member 1, wait for it to start.
Bounce member 2.
Bounce member 1.

Not always, but often, the clients report this:

```
Put 29: d16b0acd-d0d6-4722-b511-7fd975774f8c
May 10, 2017 11:41:10 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 4 of 1000.
May 10, 2017 11:41:10 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5701 as owner member
Put 30: f91ec949-19bd-4039-95d3-28c7abd0f241
May 10, 2017 11:41:15 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5702 as owner member
Put 31: 2af9fb36-d501-4b0b-9fc8-6b36d467a929
May 10, 2017 11:41:20 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5701 as owner member
Put 32: f08bd6ca-a79f-44f4-9064-42e47953c37a
```

The clients can still operate and be listening to events BUT after a period, they often disconnect:

```
May 10, 2017 11:25:04 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] HazelcastClient 3.8.1 (20170411 - f1e9264) is SHUTTING_DOWN
May 10, 2017 11:25:04 AM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] Removed connection to endpoint: [localhost]:5701, connection: ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=5, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=[localhost]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-05-10 11:25:04.021, lastWriteTime=2017-05-10 11:25:04.084, closedTime=2017-05-10 11:25:04.084, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-05-10 11:25:03.834, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-05-10 11:25:03.834, connected server version=3.8.1}
May 10, 2017 11:25:04 AM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] Removed connection to endpoint: [localhost]:5702, connection: ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=6, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=[localhost]:5702, lastReadTime=2017-05-10 11:24:59.513, lastWriteTime=2017-05-10 11:25:04.084, closedTime=2017-05-10 11:25:04.084, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-05-10 11:17:43.840, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-05-10 11:17:43.840, connected server version=3.8.1}
May 10, 2017 11:25:04 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] HazelcastClient 3.8.1 (20170411 - f1e9264) is SHUTDOWN
```

Client disconnect:

```
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] Removed connection to endpoint: [localhost]:5701, connection: ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=8, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=[localhost]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-05-10 11:45:31.791, lastWriteTime=2017-05-10 11:45:31.791, closedTime=2017-05-10 11:45:31.791, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-05-10 11:45:23.604, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-05-10 11:45:23.605, connected server version=3.8.1}
May 10, 2017 11:45:31 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.1] HazelcastClient 3.8.1 (20170411 - f1e9264) is CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
```

Member reports:

```
May 10, 2017 11:47:32 AM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
WARNING: [localhost]:5701 [dev] [3.8.1] Member having uuid 8847c2e3-2fcb-428f-a827-d0e24f5624a1 is not part of the cluster. Client Authentication rejected.
May 10, 2017 11:47:32 AM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
WARNING: [localhost]:5701 [dev] [3.8.1] Received auth from Connection[id=222, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:53883, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE] with principal ClientPrincipal{uuid='f1e5d928-23b2-4fdf-bd3f-9db1778a5a8c', ownerUuid='8847c2e3-2fcb-428f-a827-d0e24f5624a1'} , authentication failed
```

Primary Member:

```
public class HzNodeTest {
    private HazelcastInstance service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Config config = new Config();
        JoinConfig join = config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701).getJoin();
        join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        join.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
        join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost:5701").addMember("localhost:5702").setEnabled(true);
        service = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStart() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000000000);
    }
}

Secondary member:
public class HzNodeSecondaryTest {
    private HazelcastInstance service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Config config = new Config();
        JoinConfig join = config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5702).getJoin();
        join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        join.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
        join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost:5701").addMember("localhost:5702").setEnabled(true);
        service = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStart() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000000000);
    }
}

Listener:

public class HzListenerTest {
    private HazelcastInstance service;
    private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost:5701").addAddress("localhost:5702").setConnectionAttemptLimit(1000);
        service = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testListen() throws InterruptedException {
        service.getMap("TEST").addEntryListener(new Listener(), true);

        Thread.sleep(1000000);
    }

    private class Listener implements EntryAddedListener, EntryUpdatedListener, EntryRemovedListener,
            EntryEvictedListener {

        @Override
        public void entryAdded(EntryEvent event) {
            System.out.println("onAdded " + counter.getAndIncrement() + ": " + event);
        }

        @Override
        public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent event) {
            System.out.println("onEvicted " + counter.getAndIncrement() + ": " + event);
        }

        @Override
        public void entryRemoved(EntryEvent event) {
            System.out.println("onRemoved " + counter.getAndIncrement() + ": " + event);
        }

        @Override
        public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent event) {
            System.out.println("onUpdated " + counter.getAndIncrement() + ": "+ event);
        }
    }
}

Updater:

public class HzUpdaterTest {
    private HazelcastInstance service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost:5701").addAddress("localhost:5702").setConnectionAttemptLimit(1000);
        service = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        service.getMap("TEST").put("1", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSpin() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            try {
                String value = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                service.getMap("TEST").put("1", value);
                System.out.println("Put " + i + ": " + value);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a Hazelcast client is connecting to a cluster, the first member that client can establish a connection (this is when `CLIENT_CONNECTED` is fired) becomes the owner member of that client. Client gets the cluster info and other member's address from the owner member. After that, client knows all members and connect to them directly as needed.

When the member you shut down happens to be the owner member of that client, `CLIENT_DISCONNECTED` event will be fired. But within a very short time (within the same second or so), client should reestablish connection to the remaining member.

Answer (score 0):

in your logs i see

`Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 4 of 1000.`

could could try the property

`<propertyname="hazelcast.invalidation.reconciliation.interval.seconds">5</property>`